# Aptana3.4.0 Ruby2 on Rails4, cannot "Run Server", why? osx 10.8.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aptana

I created a new "Rails Project" with Aptana(3.4.0), but I cannot "Run Server", Aptana doesn't response at all, WHY? Ruby version is 2.0.0p195, Rails version is Rails 4.0.0.rc1, on Mac OSX 10.8.4. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the similar problem and solved by simply copying `(project_folder)/bin/rails` into a new folder `(project_folder)/script`